# How many webparts are available in SharePoint for displaying an excel sheet/excel report?

Tags: 2013, web-part, excel

We are doing some R&D on displaying excel sheets (simple sheets with no external data connection) and excel reports(which connect to sql db) on a SharePoint page.

I would like to know what are various web parts that are available for such purpose.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can

`Add Webpart` -> `Business Data` -> `Excel Web Access`

Also you can use Excel Services and store the Excel File in trusted location.

Comment: What is the difference between these approach? Also note that I use a user credential in excel when connecting to the analysis db. Will that work in sharepoint?

Comment: Its same. For creds you need to create a connection file I believe.

Comment: But aren't creds already embedded in the sheet? The ones you supply when making connections in excel to the analysis db.